# ajax validation login doesn't shows

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

I am using laravel 4 and I am trying to display login validation by using ajax. I have the following javascript validation:

```
jQuery('#form-signin').submit(function()
{
    var url = $(this).attr("action");
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "post",
        data: jQuery('#form-signin').serialize(),
        datatype: "json",
        beforeSend: function()
        {
            jQuery('#ajax-loading').show();
            jQuery(".validation-error-inline").hide();
        }
    })
            .done(function(data)
            {
                $('#validation-login').empty()
                if (data.validation_failed === 1)
                {
                    var arr = data.errors;
                    alert(arr);
                }
                else {
                    window.location = data.redirect_to;
                }
            })
            .fail(function(jqXHR, ajaxOptions, thrownError)
            {
                alert('No response from server');
            });
    return false;
});
```

and in my userController:

```
   public function doLogin() {
        Input::flash();
        $data = [
            "errors" => null
        ];
        if (Auth::attempt(array('email' => Input::get('email'), 'password' => Input::get('password')))) {
            return Response::json(["redirect_to" => "/"]);
        } else {
            if (Request::ajax()) {
                $response_values = array(
                    'validation_failed' => 1,
                    'errors' => 'Invalid username or password',
                );
                return Response::json($response_values);
            }else
            {
                echo 'error';
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is that it always displays "error" message, which means that jaax request isn't performed. What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In your doLogin() function try

```
return Response::json(array(
    'validation_failed' => 1,
    'errors' => 'Unknow error'
))
```

instead of

```
echo "error"
```

Comment: shows this {"validation_failed":1,"errors":"Unknow error"}

Comment: try to debug the submit callback in the browser if there is any error before sending .... Also, try this jQuery('#form-signin').submit(function(event)
{ event.preventDefault(); event.stopPropagation(); ..... the rest of your code

Comment: browser shows no error, and I tried your code and the same :/

Comment: try _jQuery('#form-signin').submit(function(event) { alert("from submit");..._  if the alert is working then I have no idea, if the alert is not working then you should check your jQuery selector if it matches the id in the html.